# Old Shatterhand badge - upvoting X competing answers with bounty in place

Tags: feature-request, badge-request, sportsmanship-badge

Coming though featured (bountied) questions gave me an idea: that would be really a gesture of ultra-fair play or "tour de force" (sorry for my english, don't know the right word for it) worth **gold badge** to **upvote a competing answer when bounty is in place**! Or, upvote `X` such competing answers.

The badge could be named like *Old Shatterhand* badge - just an idea :), or whatever better name you can invent. It could be considered a gold version of Sportsmanship. Well, not exactly, for sportsmanship the limit is 100 answers, for bountied questions the number `X` should be probably much lower. So one could end up with Old Shatterhand but not Sportsmanship then.

Or, which I like even better, don't put the `X` too high but put even harder condition - upvote competing answer with higher or equal number of votes than your own answer. Before the bounty was awarded of course.

Comment: What is "Old Shatterhand"? Is that a movie reference I'm not familiar with?

Comment: @Cody! Don't say you don't know [Old Shatterhand](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K4bEk0gX5Xw)! It was childhood hero of my generation. Your generation already doesn't now it? Don't say or I will start feeling old at my 34! :-)

Comment: Hmm, maybe it's a cultural thing. I've never heard of it, and neither have my parents.

Comment: @Cody, actually yes, may be!